# Catch exception from guzzle

Tags: php, laravel-5, exception, guzzle

I'm using laravel and I have setup the abstract class method to get response from the various APIs I'm calling. But if the API url is unreachable then it throws an exception. I know I'm missing something. Any help would be great for me.

```
$offers = [];
    try {
      $appUrl = parse_url($this->apiUrl);

      // Call Api using Guzzle
      $client = new Client('' . $appUrl['scheme'] . '://' . $appUrl['host'] . '' . $appUrl['path']);

      if ($appUrl['scheme'] == 'https') //If https then disable ssl certificate
        $client->setDefaultOption('verify', false);

      $request = $client->get('?' . $appUrl['query']);
      $response = $request->send();
      if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
        $offers = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
      }
    } catch (ClientErrorResponseException $e) {
      Log::info("Client error :" . $e->getResponse()->getBody(true));
    } catch (ServerErrorResponseException $e) {
      Log::info("Server error" . $e->getResponse()->getBody(true));
    } catch (BadResponseException $e) {
      Log::info("BadResponse error" . $e->getResponse()->getBody(true));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      Log::info("Err" . $e->getMessage());
    }

    return $offers;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should set the guzzehttp client with option **`'http_errors' => false,`**
the example code should be like this, [document:guzzlehttp client http-error option explain](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#http-errors)

> Set to false to disable throwing exceptions on an HTTP protocol errors (i.e., 4xx and 5xx responses). Exceptions are thrown by default when HTTP protocol errors are encountered.

```
$client->request('GET', '/status/500');
// Throws a GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException

$res = $client->request('GET', '/status/500', ['http_errors' => false]);
echo $res->getStatusCode();
// 500





$this->client = new Client([
    'cookies' => true,
    'headers' => $header_params,
    'base_uri' => $this->base_url,
    'http_errors' => false
]);

$response = $this->client->request('GET', '/');
if ($code = $response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
   try {
       // do danger dom things in here
   }catch (/Exception $e){
      //catch
   }

}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I get "cURL error 3: <url> malformed."

Answer (score 3):

These exceptions are not defined in guzzle officially.

These Exceptions are defined in [AWS SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Guzzle.Http.Exception.BadResponseException.html).

For official [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) you may just do following.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

....
    try {
        $response = $this->client->request($method, $url, [
            'headers'     => $headers,
            'form_params' => $form_parameters,
        ]);
        $body = (string)$response->getBody();
    } catch (ClientException $e) {
        // Do some thing here...
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        // Do some thing here...
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Do some thing here...
    }
```

Comment: I kind of agree, I do not remember why I wrote this answer two+ years back for this question.

Answer (score 0):

you could create your own exception

class CustomException extends Exception
{
}

next you throws your own exception from abstract class guzzle exception

```
catch(ConnectException $ConnectException)
    {
        throw new CustomException("Api excception ConnectException",1001);

    }
```

and then handdle in in global exception handdler render methos

```
 if($exception instanceof CustomException)
       {

          dd($exception);

       }
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how you declared those exceptions and which Guzzle version are you using but in [official documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#exceptions) those exceptions don't exist.

In your case you are probally missing `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException`.